# How can I fix CorruptedCacheException in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I was about to run the project into my device with Android Studio, these errors appeared.

[Errors appearing at Java Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHTZD.png)

I tried undoing any progress on the project to see if I didn't write something that broke the code but still got the errors. Decided to go back to a previous version on the project and still nothing. Yesterday, Android Studio was working just fine and there weren't any important changes in the project to mess it up this bad. I asked my boss what to do and he told me to use File > Invalidate cache/Restart but still, nothing changed. Then, I searched around the web and the solutions were to delete either the /cache folder or the /gradle folder. I did both and still, nothing changed.

How can you fix these errors?

Edit: I fixed it. I had to delete the *file-access.bin* in path *C:\Users(User).gradle\caches\journal-1*. After deleting it, I restarted Android Studio and rebuilt the project.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me as well! You should add your fix as a separate answer, and then accept it, rather than editing the question.

Comment: Already answered here,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55801823/13519865